# javascript: Which is the powerful Javascript - Framework to fulfill my needs

Tags: javascript, mootools, prototypejs, javascript-framework

I am building an application which uses Following features in it.

1. Popup Window
2. Transition effects.
3. Heavy contents in popup Window(like thousands of tags).
4. Pipelining for client server communication.(like BigPipe in Facebook)
5. Faster to switch between pages.

In this case,

Is Prototype more superior than mootools?

Is there any other more powerfull frameworks i should use to build the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these features are delivered out of the box in Prototype, jQuery or MooTools.

For app development, consider to use OOP and build modular components. This maybe easier in frameworks that provide OOP structures including Events and Options like MooTools does but it also not impossible in Frameworks without OOP, like jQuery. You would plug in stand-alone Class inheritance and create your own modular namespaces. You and your team just need to be more strict, otherwise its easy to end up in a stack of chained spaghetti code.

One of the downside in non-OOP frameworks is, that you can not extend/inherit existing framework code to plug in your own solution. jQuery provides a huge UI library, with varying quality of code; but you will be mostly stuck with options, events and features those plugins provide out of the box, unable to extend or reuse their internals.

OOP frameworks support the roll-your-own idea, helping with a lot of modules; while jQuery developers tend to just-solve-the-problem … by including a lot of different UI plugins.

Strong OOP framework with modular dependencies: MooTools, Dojo, YUI, Closure Library.

Comment: i designed the application almost 70% in mootools but working too slow. thats why i m thinking about to change the javascript-framework itself.

Comment: Slow JavaScript does not have to originate from the framework, and Prototype will not make things magically faster. There are a lot of bottlenecks on all frameworks, like selectors, iterations, events, creating huge amounts of elements, etc., that need to be considered and avoided (using reducing selectors with reasonable caching, choosing for loops over each, event delegation, etc).

Comment: Most everything in MooTools is highly optimized (and every decent JavaScript library), the biggest performance mistake out there is not caching your selectors, which has nothing to do with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.com/ jQuery is another good framework. They all have similar features. Pick the one that pleases you most or has readily available plugins for the features you need.

Comment: thanks for reply.....I am using mootools rite now.

Answer (score 0):

I second digitalrald's sentiment. Changing your library isn't going to magically fix slow code. I recommend running through some of these common optimizations after you have properly profiled your application and can pin-point which methods and lookups are slowing you down the most:

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices